# PreviousPage and control created at run-time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

At run-time I add a textbox with

```
         Dim MRNCell As New TableCell
         MRNCell.ID = "MRNCell"
         Dim txtMRN As New TextBox
         txtMRN.ID = "NewMRN"
         MRNCell.Controls.Add(txtMRN)
         MRNRow.Cells.Add(MRNCell)
```

I then attempt to access the Text property in a public readonly Property using  PreviousPage. Below are three renditions of the Property, none of which works.

```
Public ReadOnly Property NewMRN() As String
    Get
        Dim NewMRNNum As TextBox = CType(Me.FindControl("NewMRN"), TextBox)
        'NewMRNNum = Nothing
        Return NewMRNNum.Text
    End Get
End Property    

Public ReadOnly Property NewMRN() As String
    Get
        Dim sNewMRN As String = String.Empty

        For Each MyRow As TableRow In MyTable.Rows
            For Each MyCell As TableCell In MyRow.Cells
                If MyCell.ID = "MRNCell" Then
                    For Each MyControl As Control In MyCell.Controls
                        Dim MRNBox As New TextBox
                        MRNBox = TryCast(MyControl, TextBox)
                        If Not (MRNBox Is Nothing) Then
                            sNewMRN = MRNBox.Text
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

            Next
        Next
        'There is only one TextBox in the table and sNewMRN = ""
        Return sNewMRN
    End Get
End Property    

Public ReadOnly Property NewMRN() As String
    Get
        'For this one the TextBox is declared Public in the class
        'The Text property = ""
        Return txtMRN.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

I have two public readonly properties. The first one returns the Text property from a TextBox created in the designer and the other attempts to return the Text property created at run-time. One works and the other either throws an exception or returns an empty string, depending on which of the three methods I use.

```
   If Not PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
        'Works
        Dim sMessageID As String = PreviousPage.MessageID
        'Does not work
        Dim sNewMRN As String = PreviousPage.NewMRN
        Literal1.Text = "<p>" & sMessageID & "</p><p>" & sNewMRN & "</p>"

    End If
```

So, how can I access the Text property of a Textbox created at run-time, have that value returned in a public readonly property, so I can access it with PreviousPage?

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Once again, writing the question made me think about it enough that I came up with a solution. I add the textbox at design-time and set the visible property to false. Then at run-time I make it visible and add it to the table row cell.

Greg